# Python backend with JS frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, bottle

I'm creating a Python-powered web framework aiming to make use of javascript as minimal as it possible. Need to make something lightweight like [uilang](http://uilang.com/) to pass events to my Python code. I suppose that should be jQuery solution somehow pinging kind of observer object(?).

I have discovered some efforts to create pure-Python interface like [Remi](https://github.com/dddomodossola/remi) but still have no clue how should I reimplement it in my code.

Let's say I make a class like that:

```
class WebView():
    def __init__(self, template, **callbacks):
        """
        Callbacks are dict, {'object': callback}
        """
        self.template = template
        self.customJS = None
        for obj, call in callbacks:
            self.setCallback(obj, call)

    def __call__():
        """
        Here I return template
        Assume {{customJS}} record in template, to be simple
        """
        return bottle.template(self.template, customJS = self.customJS)

    def setCallback(self, obj, call):
        """
        Build custom js to insert 
        """
        self.customJS += ('<script ....%s ... %s' % (obj, call))
```

So, how could I make JS to pass an event from, say, pressing button back to my callback?

I understand that question might be on the edge of being too broad, but I'm solely trying to be as descriptive as possible because I really don't know JS at all.

Comment: You need to do some more research into how client and server technologies work together before setting out on such an epic endevour. May be start with: https://pythonprogramming.net/jquery-flask-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do it with [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) too, however i don't think it's the best way. You can use [websocket-python](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client) library on the python side, and on the website, you just send a websocket message on every button click callback.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is you don't need javascript for a python web framework. You would be fine serving pages with flask or django without the single line of JS.

These pages would be pretty static with a few forms but would work perfectly.

Now if you want to have more dynamic content and interaction you'll probably need JS, and use [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to asynchronously call your python backend on events. But in order to do so properly, you should start by learning JS.